# How can I solve "entry point not found" error in RAD Studio 10.3.3?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

When I try to run my project, I get an error:

> The procedure entry point @System@Classes@TFieldsCache@#bcctr$qqrv could not be located in the DLL vclx260.bpl

Followed by similar messages concerning other DLLs.

I tried applying the 10.3.2 Runtime Packages Compatibility Patch that is available, because it fit my circumstances perfectly, but it had no effect, same errors.

I uninstalled C++Builder 10.3.3 and reinstalled it, no effect, same errors.

This same project runs fine on another computer running 10.3.3.

I'm kind of at the end of my rope on this, hoping someone can help.

Comment: When you say you applied the Runtime Packages Compatibilty Patch, was that applied to your existing 10.3.3? Because that is a 10.3.2 patch, so you would have needed to uninstall 10.3.3, install 10.3.2, apply the patch, and then upgrade to 10.3.3. Though, I would have expected 10.3.3 to already include all of the 10.3.1 and 10.3.2 patches from the get-go.

Comment: I did did apply the 10.3.2 patch to 10.3.3 because it was all I could find.  I've now installed 10.4.2 which has eliminated this problem.